# using volley makes some activity leaked

Tags: android

code source in https://github.com/drduan/ClassDemo

```
In neusoft.duanxudong.com.classdemo:1.0:1.
* neusoft.duanxudong.com.classdemo.activity.ClassesActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT thread com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.<Java Local>     (named 'Thread-1595')
* references com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.mErrorListener
* references     neusoft.duanxudong.com.classdemo.activity.ClassesActivity$6.this$0     (anonymous class implements com.android.volley.Response$ErrorListener)
* leaks neusoft.duanxudong.com.classdemo.activity.ClassesActivity instance

* Reference Key: b9dbaa92-4044-4c00-b520-a459eb5a31cb
* Device: YuLong Coolpad Coolpad 8675-A Coolpad8675-A
* Android Version: 4.4.4 API: 19
* Durations: watch=5049ms, gc=152ms, heap dump=2606ms, analysis=17814ms
```

I think the main question maybe in this class

[2 CacheRequest](https://github.com/drduan/ClassDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/neusoft/duanxudong/com/classdemo/util/CacheRequest.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a known issue with Volley. Please take the latest version to check if it's still there.